# video not auto playing in html page when muted tag is removed

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a html page, in which I used a video tag:

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
           <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Mt_Baker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The problem is that, when I remove the `muted="muted"` attribute,
ie:

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
           <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Mt_Baker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

the video autoplay stops. how can I resolve this?

I've tried to play video using javascript but it results in DOM Promise Exception.

Comment: Do you use Chrome?

Comment: You can simply put `autoplay` instead of `autoplay="autoplay"`, same for `playsinline` and `loop`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Chrome, anything that plays sound will not work unless the user clicks something first. See the announcement [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).
A solution could be using JavaScript to simulate the click.

```
document.addEventListener('click', musicPlay);
function musicPlay() {
    document.getElementById('ID').play();
    document.removeEventListener('click', musicPlay);
}
```

If you can't get it working with JavaScript, Google's solution is to add

```
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var context = new AudioContext();
}
</script>
</head>
```

If it still doesn't work, for more best practices recommended by Google look [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio).